Who watches the watchers?
If you feel you're being targeted and threatened by a mod, what are your courses of action to deal with this?

The answers to that question answer this one. You could also pick this other one as dupe target.

@yivi This is the best: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/369403

See What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?
In essence:

You can involve meta.
You can ask other users for advice in chat.
You can involve other moderators.
You can involve the SE CMs (paid employees by SE, not normal moderators).

Meaning, there's a lot of oversight here.
